# Is there an open source C# .net mvc project that eliminates the ramp up time when developing Appfuse applications for new customers?

Tags: java, .net, web-applications, appfuse

For example, I am looking for an Appfuse equivalent for .NET MVC apps.

I use Appfuse in Java to crank out a quick web app pre-configured with the front-end and backend frameworks of my choice.  Appfuse used ANT or Maven to build a web application.

Seeing as .net has equivalent frameworks & tools to Java, i.e. ANT and NANT, Hibernate and NHibernate, log4j and log4net, Spring and Spring.Net; Is there an equivalent project to Appfuse for .net?

Appfuse is an open source project and application that uses open source tools built on the Java platform to help you develop Web applications quickly and efficiently.

It was originally developed to eliminate the ramp-up time found when building new web applications for customers.

Comment: Anybody got anything for this yet?

Comment: Appfuse is almost like a web-app factory if you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest thing to what you are looking for is called [S#arp Architecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/)

> Pronounced "Sharp Architecture," this
>   is a solid architectural foundation
>   for rapidly building maintainable web
>   applications leveraging the ASP.NET
>   MVC framework with NHibernate. The
>   primary advantage to be sought in
>   using any architectural framework is
>   to decrease the code one has to write
>   while increasing the quality of the
>   end product. A framework should enable
>   developers to spend little time on
>   infrastructure details while allowing
>   them to focus their attentions on the
>   domain and user experience.
>   Accordingly, S#arp Architecture
>   adheres to the following key
>   principles:
>
> ```
> * Focused on Domain Driven Design
> * Loosely Coupled
> * Preconfigured Infrastructure
> * Open Ended Presentation
> ```

**Update:** The Sharp Architecture project is now located [here](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture):

Comment: Yeah!  That's exactly what I meant! :)  Thanks you the man chief!